# Wi-Fi scanning for SSID in Meteor

Tags: cordova, meteor, wifi, cordova-plugins, ssid

I want to know what's my mobile's current Wi-Fi SSID before starting the server using Cordova and Meteor.

I added this code in the client side of `Meteor.startup()`:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
        cordova.plugin.WifiWizard2.getConnectedSSID(function(success, fail) {
            console.log("success");
        });
    }
});
```

I added this plugin to my Meteor app:

```
meteor add cordova:wifiwizard2@2.1.1
```

But after running the code locally I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'WifiWizard2' of undefined

Can you give some suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

`fs` is a node api and as such is not available on the client.

It will not be possible to get the Wi-Fi details of the client unless you are using cordova or something similar.

If you move this code to the `Meteor.startup()` for the server and your server has one of the [following](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wifi-control#methods), you will be able to see the Wi-Fi networks that the server is in range of (obviously only if it has a Wi-Fi card).

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side, as in the browser, understandably **this is not allowed**. This level of access would be a **high security risk**, since getting the SSID is a low-level task.

But if you'd develop a **desktop application using JavaScript**, then it would be possible. Check out **[Electron](https://electronjs.org/)**, the framework, which is used by **[many desktop applications](https://electronjs.org/apps)**.

...or maybe **[Meteor Desktop](https://github.com/wojtkowiak/meteor-desktop)**?